# Black Borders in Adobe Air IOS

Tags: ios, iphone, actionscript-3, air

My application on IOS created with Adobe Air is displaying random black bars on the top and bottom of the screen using an iPhone 5 and all other 4-inch devices.

I have exported the same app on Android, Desktop and HTML and the aspect ratio is rendered correctly. I've also tried changing the stage dimensions to match the iPhone's screen resolution to no avail.

I have enabled high resolution in Adobe Flash CS5 and also targeted the iPhone exclusively. My render method is direct, and yet nothing seems to make the borders disappear. This is what it looks like:

[image]

I also tried creating a blank Adobe Air project, and the bars still come up regardless.
I have used Adobe Air SDK 3.2, 3.4, and the latest SDK and nothing works. What is happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the proper launch image for the device you're on. See [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/launch-images-ios.html) and here: 
[iOS lauch image specs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS901d38e593cd1bac1e63e3d129907d2886-8000.html#WS901d38e593cd1bac58d08f9112e26606ea8-8000)